# Meaning of "Kingdom Come: Deliverance"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

A PC game called ["Kingdom Come: Deliverance"](https://www.kingdomcomerpg.com/) was released a few days ago.

What does the title mean? "Kingdom Come**s**" would be understandable for me, but "Kingdom Come"...? What could "Deliverance" mean in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Kingdom come" is an idiom meaning "eternity" (both in the religious sense of "afterlife" and the literal sense of "forever").

It derives from the Lord's Prayer:

> Our Father in heaven, hallowed be your name. Your kingdom come. Your will be done, on earth as it is in heaven.

In the prayer itself, "Your kingdom come" is in the imperative mood, so it takes no "s" at the end.

A related idiom is "to blow/blast/etc. to kingdom come" meaning "to obliterate completely".

In the context of the title, it was likely used both because it sounds cool (in the context of the second idiom) and because it's a pun on the game taking place in an actual kingdom.

As for "Deliverance", the literal meaning is "salvation" - particularly religious salvation in the sense of being accepted and protected by God. I'm not sure whether it relates to any themes in the game, or whether it's just another instance of a cool-sounding word.

Comment: **Deliverance** can refer to a secular salvation too. And **kingdom come** can also refer to a very destructive termination, such as being nuked or hit by a bazooka round etc, such as one often finds in video games.  *Let's hit them with all we've got and blow them to kingdom come.*  A paraphrase might be **blow them to smithereens**. Apocalyptic endings.

Comment: It is worth noting that the language in this prayer is from over 400 years ago (the King James Bible), so it is very archaic. So you should not worry about understanding the specific grammatical breakdown of this sentence. Most people today know this phrase only as a stock biblical phrase; they do not think of "come" as being in the imperative mood, or even a verb at all. [But for the record, modern translations of the bible translate this as "We pray that your kingdom will come."]

Answer (score 1):

After reading up on the meaning of both parts of the name separately, my best guess would be something all g the lines of saved by a new life or starting over like second chance type thing. Since kingdom come means afterlife or even new life or new world like after some catastrophic occurrence the wold starts anew after previous one being destroyed that could either be in religious way as judgement day or also in a more literal way like one civilization dying and a new one emerging in it wake etc... And deliverance could mean salvation in religious way but also it non religious way. Like deliverance from war. Meaning being saved from war etc. I am only several hours in the game but the plot seems to match my theory rather well. Henry was ambitious to go out in the world. His village got burned down, everything that linked him to his past life except sir Rodzig is gone(although hes more of a means for change then a link to the past if you think about it). We have Henry who almost died and his old life is gone and he cant go back to it. That's where I think "kingdom come" part comes in. And then he's quite literally delivered from death in both figurative and literal meaning. And into a new life of excitement and such.